# Setting float precision in hdf5 dataset

Tags: python-2.7, precision, hdf5, h5py

I'm surprised I wasn't able to find an answer to this question. I'm writing float values to an hdf5 dataset, and I want to set the precision at 10 decimals. From the [documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html) on hdf5 datasets, there doesn't seem to be any way to set precision. The closest I get is doing either 'float32' or 'float64', but 'float32' cuts off my numbers.  File size is a big concern for me, and the unnecessary digits for 'float64' make the file significantly larger. Is it possible to choose precision with hdf5?

An example of my issue:
With the true value of data[0] being 0.0066896507

```
group.create_dataset(name, data=data, dtype='float64')
```

data[0] yields 0.0066896506999999999, but

```
group.create_dataset(name, data=data, dtype='float32')
```

gives me 0.0066896505, which is incorrect. Other numbers in the dataset are even more incorrect.

It's also odd, because when I do

```
x = h5py.File(my_file,'r')
print(x['dataset'][0])
```

it gives me the correct number. But when I just type `x['dataset'][0]` into the console, it gives what I wrote above. How is the data actually being stored? Is it really giving those extra digits? As you can see I'm a little new to hdf5 (and python in general). Thanks for the help.

Comment: `float32` and `float64` are the standard float types in most compilers (`float` and `double` in `c` compilers).  Those use 4 and 8 bytes per number.  Processors and compilers are designed to work efficiently with those sizes.  Trying to use 6 bytes (or worse 5 or 7) would significantly reduce efficiency without a reducing memory usage much.

Comment: If I send this hdf5 file to someone else, would they see the numbers as 10 precision or more?

Comment: This may be a print precision issue rather than a storage one.

Comment: That's very possible. I guess it's not an issue then, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create custom precision types, you'll need to drop to the low-level bindings of h5py, specifically the function/types outlined http://api.h5py.org/h5t.html#atomic-classes. See https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/h5py/h5t.pyx#L202 for an example of how this is done (for half/16-bit floats).

However, this probably isn't what you want (given the reference to decimal digits). Whilst base-10 based floating point numbers exist (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format), in practice if you're using python all floating point numbers are base-2. This means you care about the number of bits it's stored in (and what format, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats). Also worth noting is it's entirely possible to print more digits than you have precision for (e.g. I can print float32 which stores ~7 significant figures with 30 significant figures, but that doesn't mean I have 30 significant figures worth of precision). So based on the fact that you care about at least 10 significant figures worth of precision, you should use float64 (which is also known as double, binary64)

If you are concerned about file size, it's worth looking at h5py's compression support, see http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#filter-pipeline.

Comment: Thank you. I believe it was a print issue, and falls under your "print more digits than you have precision for" statement.